# MySQL SELECT Query Returning Inconsistent Results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with 6 columns: id (Primary and auto-incrementing), latitude (double), longitude (double), data_points (int), data_total (double), avg_strength (double).

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM iPhoneTest WHERE latitude=$lat AND longitude=$lon LIMIT 1
```

$lat and $lon are defined from $_GET (These are not the problem, though)

My problem arises with the data_points and data_total columns, as the query returns the wrong values for them.  Here is the section of my code where I process the row:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  
$pts = $row["data_points"] + 1; 
$tot = $row["data_total"] + $str;
$avg = $tot / $pts;
```

Below is the output from two different examples.  As you can see in both examples, one iteration (Me changing the values and reloading the page) returns an incorrect value, while the rest return the correct value (This can be seen by the fact that the data_points column should only go up 1 each time).

Here is the line that outputs everything ($pts being data_points, $avg being avg_strength, and $tot being data_total):

```
echo $pts . " " . $avg . " " . $tot;
```

And the two examples:

For example 1, I used the values 5, 7, 7, 10 to add to the data_total.

```
1 5 5    
3 5.7 17  <--- Bad query occurs here
4 6 24
5 6.8 34
```

For example 2, I used the values 5, 6, 7, 8 to add to the data_total.

```
1 5 5
2 5.5 11
3 6 18
5 6.6 33 <--- Bad query occurs here
```

Unfortunately, there is no pattern to the bad queries.  I've had tests in which all queries returned the wrong values and tests like the ones above in which all but one query works fine.  The only thing I've noticed is that if I use the same value multiple times in a row, the query works fine every time. Also, if I use the same pattern of values (such as in the examples above) multiple times, I get the same exact output.

I can also confirm from prior testing that the query itself is returning incorrect values, rather than my math being faulty.

So far, I have tried emptying all values from the table, deleting the table and remaking it, and deleting the database itself and remaking it.  None had any effect.

Has anyone ever dealt with something similar and/or know how I can fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `$str`, and why are you adding it to `$row['data_total']`?

Comment: @Barmar I misread the question; have deleted my answer.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What makes something a "bad query"?

Comment: I also don't understand the question. You will need to show us what's in DB and the expected results. What Barmar said also about `$str`, you're unclear about that.

Comment: I imagine you have someone else using the page at the same time. Check your logs. Also, make sure you're using POST requests if you're updating the database. GET requests ought to be idempotent, since things like browser prefetching or search engines can request them at any time.

Comment: $str is the value i am adding to the total.  In practice, each time a user adds $str, it should be added to the total for that coordinate.  By bad query, I mean it is returning the wrong data.  I am looking at the database as I refresh, and what I see on the page is not consistent with what I see in the database.  Hope this clears things up.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

a "LIMIT 1" query without an ORDER BY statement doesn't guarantee you the same results everytime.   Are you sure there is only 1 possible row for  one ($lat,$lon) couple ?

check if this return NO rows :

`select * from iPhoneTest group by latitude, longitude  having count(*) > 1`

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so it looks like it is working.  I know my phrasing in the original post is a bit confusing, but hopefully someone can use this in the future.

It turned out to be a problem with Safari.  When I run the same exact query on Chrome, it works as expected.  I still have no idea about Safari caused it, but I can confirm that it was a browser issue, not a code or database issue, as nothing was changed when I ran it on Chrome.

Comment: **No!** **NO!** Excuse me for intervening noisily here, but this has nothing to do with your browser. An error in your query is causing you to receive *unpredictable* results from your MySQL server. @Laloutre has described the problem correctly. You need an `ORDER BY` clause to go with your `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: The only time I see unpredictable results is in safari, though.  If it is an error in my query, why does it work in all other browsers?

Comment: @yankees96 Are you modifying the database in a GET request?

Comment: Yes.  The URL, in practice, will be called from an iphone app.

Comment: @yankees96 Yeah, don't do that. I think you have to use a POST request.